# How to sort and output data stored in a list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, loops, timespan

I have a application which reads a text file with dates.

Please note that I am still learning C#

the content in the text file is something like this:
**i.e I the content wasn't sorted but I have already stored them in a list and sorted in ASC order.**

```
02/10/1998
03/10/1998
07/10/1998
10/10/1998
17/10/1998
20/10/1998
```

The text file has more the a hundred dates, due to the fact that I am using a phone i can't type all the text and can't write the entire code.

basically the purpose of the application is to write to a new text file, content with **week-blocks from a timespan
ie:

```
Week : Sunday 27 1998 to Saturday 03 1998
Friday 02 1998
Fri 2 98
02/10/98
Saturday 03 1998
Sat 2 98
03/10/1998
Week : Sunday 04 1998 to Saturday 10 1998
Wednesday 07 1998
Wed 7 98
07/10/1998
Saturday 10 1998
Sat 10 98
10/10/1998

//And so on till last date
```

The output should always start with the First Sunday to Saturday and end with the last Sunday to Saturday.

All I need to know is how to generate such a output by **week-blocks from a timespan**?

I have already written the code to sort from list and now I think I have to parse Date formats

```
var sortedlist = stulist.OrderBy(s => s.DOB);

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "ddddMMMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "dddMMMd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt3 = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I think I have to loop but I cant figure out what to specify in my **while loop**.

**Any Help will highly be appreciated**

What difference would:

```
tx.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dddd dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

have with if I keep the ParseExact?

```
tx.WriteLine(dt);
```

Comment: You should edit your question and clarify that you actually want to know how to get those week-blocks from a timespan. Currently it's not clear whether that or the datetime-format is the core of your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for informing me, I've editted.

Comment: Do you want to have all the week-blocks or only those where you also have dates to display?

Comment: @T_D I should only have those I have to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. I try to recapitulate what you are probably doing. You seem to have a `Student` class having (among others) a field `DOB`. I assume that it is of type `DateTime`. Then you must be doing something like this in order to read the text file:

```
var students = new List<Student>();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("my file path");
CultureInfo southAfricanCuture = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");
foreach (string l in lines) {
    DateTime d;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(l, "dd/MM/yyyy", southAfricanCuture,
                               DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out d))
    {
        students.Add(new Student { DOB = d });
    }
}
```

We need to use `TryParseExact` in order to have right order of day and month. But maybe I'm just using the wrong culture.

I.e. parsing occurs when converting a date given as text into a `DateTime`. In order to disply the dates, later, you will have to convert them back to `string` by formatting them (not Parsing!).

To go on, we will need this helper method:

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    // Since Sunday = 0 and we want sunday to be the first day of week:
    int dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
    return date.AddDays(-dayOfWeek);
}
```

Now, let's create date blocks using LINQ (make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of your code):

```
var dtfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
Calendar cal = dtfi.Calendar;

var dateBlocks = students
    .Select(s => s.DOB)
    .GroupBy(d => 100 * d.Year +
                  cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    .OrderBy(g => g.First()); // Order the groups by first date found in them.
```

And now, let's create the output:

```
foreach (var block in dateBlocks) {
    // Week header
    DateTime firstDayOfWeek = FirstDateOfWeek(block.First());
    DateTime lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.AddDays(6);
    string weekHeader = String.Format(southAfricanCuture,
        "Week : {0:dddd dd/MM yyyy} to {1:dddd dd/MM yyyy}",
        firstDayOfWeek, lastDayOfWeek);
    Console.WriteLine(weekHeader);

    // Week details.
    // If the dates appear in wrong order in the input file,
    // order the days within the groups.
    foreach (DateTime date in block.OrderBy(d => d)) {
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("    dddd dd/MM yyyy", southAfricanCuture));
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("    ddd d/M yy", southAfricanCuture));
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("    dd/MM/yy", southAfricanCuture));
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

As you can see, working with dates is a complicated matter.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for, so basically I should use date.ToString for my outputs

Answer (score 1):

There is a linq tag in this qwestion.I tried to do that in linq

Create list with values

```
    var lst = new List<string> {"02/10/1998",
    "03/10/1998",
    "07/10/1998",
    "10/10/1998",
    "17/10/1998",
    "20/10/1998"
    };
```

List of datetime values

```
var DateList = (from value in lst
                   select DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Lets do our list more usable

```
List<MyClass> lst3 = DateList.Select(p => new MyClass
        {
            DT = p,
            WeekOfYear = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(p , DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek.Monday),
            FirstDayOfWeek = p.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - p.DayOfWeek),
            LastDayOfWeek = p.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday - p.DayOfWeek)
        }).OrderBy(x=>x.WeekOfYear).ToList();
```

Now you can show result

```
 int current_week=-1;
        foreach (MyClass o in lst3)
        {
            if (current_week > o.WeekOfYear)
            {
                current_week = o.WeekOfYear;
                Console.WriteLine("Week: {0} {1} to {2} {3}", o.FirstDayOfWeek.DayOfWeek.ToString() ,o.FirstDayOfWeek, o.LastDayOfWeek.DayOfWeek.ToString(), o.LastDayOfWeek);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", o.DT.DayOfWeek.ToString(), o.DT);
        }
```

Comment: This should work, At the time I posted this question I was a beginner when it comes LINQ.

Comment: @Brian02 What do you mean by that? Does this answer help you?